# Subsequent displays of custom Tooltip has ugly black edging around border

Tags: c#, .net, tooltip

I created a simple Tooltip class which I'd like to enhance with more features but with just a basic Tooltip I'm running into an issue of it getting an ugly edging along the border when it appears on the second time or thereafter. The first time it displays, it appears correct.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class CToolTip : ToolTip
{

    public CToolTip()
    {
        this.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(this.OnPopup);
        this.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(this.OnDraw);
    }

    private void OnPopup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ToolTipSize = new Size(200, 200);
    }

    private void OnDraw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightYellow, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200));
    }
}
```

I added the CToolTip and a button to a form. Added an event handler for the hover event and display it on a button hover.

```
this.button1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_MouseHover);

    private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cTip.SetToolTip(button1, "This is a test");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being this line. When I removed it, the problem went away.

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
```